Plotly legend has a slider that I would like to get rid
Is there any way to remove the slider and extend the vertical axis of the legend. I could not find a parameter "height" in the legend.
Regards,
Pierre


Can you add your code? Minimal code?

Based on your screenshot, it looks like your figure height is too low to show all of the items in the legend.

if you display it in web browser then you may try to add some CSS to modify height or font size, or other elements.

Try this: fig.update_layout(height=500)

Update: None of the solutions works. Except having a second empty row. To extend the figure height without compromising the height of the first row.
